# Reading output after Linux cmd execution is going to infinite loop

Tags: java, linux, jakarta-ee, java-io, jsch

I am executing a cmd from jsch , once command is completed I need to show the command output. while reading the command output its taking long time and its ns not coming from the while loop even after execution of command. The following is my code:

```
java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");


        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
        session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications","publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
        session.setPassword(password);

        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected");

        channel=session.openChannel("shell");
        OutputStream ops = channel.getOutputStream();
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(ops, true);

         channel.connect();
         ps.println(cmd);
        InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();
        byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
        while(channel.getExitStatus() == -1){
          while(in.available()>0){
            int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
            if(i<0)break;
            System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
          }
          if(channel.isClosed()){
            System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
            break;
          }
          try{Thread.sleep(3000);}catch(Exception ee){}
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the **exit** command at the end of the command.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have observed so far, `channel.isClosed()` is true only once the SSH daemon has sent you all the content of the output streams (stdout and stderr).

If this content is big, it will not fit completely in the buffer of the TCP connection between sshd and your process and the channel will remain open forever. The problem is even worse when you may have a lot of content in both stdout and stderr because you don't know which stream to consume in priority. The calls to `read()` are blocking without a possibility to timeout.

The solution we use is to cautiously consume all the content of stdout and stderr simultaneously in the main thread and not to call `read()` on any stream if we are not sure it won't block.

```
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder error = new StringBuilder();

        InputStream out = channel.getInputStream();
        InputStream err = channel.getErrStream();

        while(!channel.isClosed() || out.available() > 0 || err.available() > 0) {
            if (out.available() > 0) {
                size = out.read(cbuf);
                if (size > 0) {
                    result.append(new String(cbuf, 0, size));
                } 
                // normally the 'if' is useless as available() guarantee size > 0
                // it's just an extra-precaution
            } else if (err.available() > 0) {
                size = err.read(cbuf);
                if (size > 0) {
                    error.append(new String(cbuf, 0, size));
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem when I read the InputStream from a UNIX server.

`out.available()` becomes 0 after the bytes are read in the while loop and along with that we should have noticed `channel.getExitStatus()` is -1 which indicates a failure. The command execution was a failure.

Hence, I have decided to use the log from `channel.getOutputStream()`. Below is a reusable method that I have created which helps to execute command in the remote server and returns the log as String. We can manipulate the log data which contains the output from server, (few things might be improper, please, ignore that)

```
public static String executeCommand(String command, int timeout) {
        try {
            Channel channel = getSession().openChannel("shell");
            setChannel(channel);

            PrintStream standard = System.out;
            OutputStream out = getChannel().getOutputStream();
            PrintStream commander = new PrintStream(out, true);
            
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);

            getChannel().setOutputStream(ps, true);
            getChannel().connect();

            for (String c : command.split(";")) {
                commander.println(c);
                try {Thread.sleep(timeout);}catch(Exception e) {}
            }

            ps.flush();
            commander.flush();
            
            System.setOut(standard);
            System.out.println(baos.toString());
            
            out.close();
            baos.close();
            
            System.out.println("Command executed successfully - "+command);
            unloadChannel();
            
            return baos.toString();

        }catch (JSchException e) {
            System.out.println("Channel connection failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
            //throw new RuntimeException("Shell channel connection failed");
        }catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO Exception occurred");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }

    }
```

Make sure the channel and streams are closed for avoiding leaks... Feel free to provide suggestions if I had made any mistake.

I know this is a workaround but did not have any other working solution...